# Access outlook folder link primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access, outlook

I have an access database where i created a link to an active outlook folder. The problem is this linked outlook folder has no primary ID for me to work of. Adding an autonumber seems to not be allowed in a linked table. Is there a way Around it, can an autonumber be added to a query of this table?

Answer (score 2):

I used Received Time as primary key, since it is unique. If you found any other solution, please share.